# Assign a picture URL to a page via PHP

Tags: php, images, post-thumbnails

I would like to assign a picture URL via PHP to a page. I’ve googled already but just found something like this:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/

Does anyone have an idea how I can assign a picture URL to a page via PHP?

Furthermore the picture has to be integrated via the URL and not be downloaded in my media library and not be applied from there. So external.

What I mean is this here (Called Featured Image in English):

[image: screenshot of portion of admin dashboard with relevant field highlighted in red]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `add_post_meta` function:

```
add_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_custom_image_url', 'http://domain.com/image.jpg', true );
```

The code above assumes that **a)** you will have only one image per page; and **b)** you are in a loop so `get_the_ID` will return a valid ID of the page you want to attach the meta-data to. Documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/).